# How to correct for inability to load DAO DLL in Access 2003 on Windows 7?

Tags: ms-access, vba, windows-7, dao

I have an application that uses the MS Access 2003 front end to connect to both a MS SQL and a Sybase database. This application uses VBA (Visual Basic 6) and this cannot be changed. We are in the midst of a conversion from Windows XP (where the application runs fine) to Windows 7.

On Windows 7, attempts to connect to the Sybase databsae fail. The application uses a pass through query and when the failure occurs, I receive the following message:

```
An unexpected error occurred in Call_SP.
Error number: 48
Error description: Error in loading DLL
Error source: Secure open security
```

The particular line of code where this is throwing the error is:

```
For Each qryDef In dbLocal.QueryDefs
```

The items in this line of code are defined like this:

```
Dim dbLocal As Database
Dim qryDef As QueryDef

Set dbLocal = CurrentDb()
```

When originally launching the application, there was a missing reference for Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library. I copied the dao360.dll file to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO, registered it using regsvr32.exe, and set the reference (Tools -> References) to this file.

At this point, I suspect the problem may have something to do with user rights on this machine, but I'm stuck on where to start. Users do have "read and execute" rights on the dao360.dll file.

We have a lot of legacy apps written in Access, so our systems use Access 2003, but Word, Excel, and Outlook 2010. We are moving to Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: I wonder about the missing dll, because this PC has never had anything earlier than Access 2010 yet it still has DAO 3.6 libraries. Have you tried reinstalling Access?

Comment: VBA 6 is not Visual Basic 6.  This sort of misquoting causes no end of confusion for people, even though Microsoft does it themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was in your shoes, I would try the following:

1. Remove and re-install Access

   And I would run a registry cleaner like CCleaner to remove broken library reference from the registry before re-installing Access and applying all updates.
   The fact that the dao360.dll was missing or improperly registered shows that there is at least one installation issue on that machine.
   Also, remove and re-install your ODBC drivers for the other databases.
2. Try on the same machine from a different user

   Create a new user on the machine, then log under that user and check if you still get the issue.
3. Try from a different machine

   Use the same database, make sure the DAO references are selected, and try code query again.
   If it still doesn't work, then there is another issue somewhere, and it's not related necessarly to DAO.
4. You mention using Sybase and SQL Server.

   Are the ODBC drivers functioning properly? Could there be some corruption there too on the machine?
   What if you create a new database and try a single pass-through query using the same connection string?
5. 32 and 64 bits mixup

   Are you sure all dependent software and database drivers are installed for 32bit?
   If you are trying to access an ODBC data source that uses a 64bit driver from a 32bit app, it will fail.
   In Win7 x64 the ODBC console available from the *Administrative Tools* in the *Control Panel* is **not** 32bit!
   You need to create your DSN using `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` instead.

Comment: Unregistering the DAO DLL and then reinstalling Access has corrected the problem. Part of the issue seems to be that Office 2010 (without Access) was installed after Access 2003.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I came up with was to use weak typing, and to reference all DAO objects through CurrentDb. *The only references I have in my project are VBA and the Microsoft Access Object Library, which are required anyway.* It is a bit radical, but it does give you something that can be deployed on any platform.

The project of every newly created Access database includes a reference to a DAO library. But DAO library references are no longer updated when databases are deployed on different machines. *That feature was broken in Access 2007, when the DAO library was renamed.*

In your example, this would be:

```
Dim qryDef As Object
For Each qryDef In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
```

Comment: I suspect that you had installation issues. DAO is part of MSAccess and you can't really write any VBA database code without it.   Did you simply try removing and re-installing Access from scratch?  Another weird issue as well could be caused by enabling compression on your C: drive. [I had a strange issue once](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2009/ms-access-upsizing-to-sql-server-2008/) with dao360.dll because it was transparently compressed by the OS.

Comment: In the contrary, my VBA project uses plenty of DAO objects, it just does not have any references to DAO libraries. Are you sure that you understand how weak typing works? It is a technique that is used to avoid referencing COM libraries, usually to avoid deployment issues.

Comment: I'm very familiar with late binding, thank you. However, you should __not__ have to use that for the most basic library installed by default with every single version of Access. Having to resort to late binding to solve that particular issue within Access itself is a pretty good indicator of DLL conflicts or corruption (possibly of the registry) that may be solved by a complete re-install.

Comment: I agree that the project of every newly created Access database includes a reference to a DAO library. But DAO library references are no longer updated when databases are deployed on different machines. That feature was broken in Access 2007, when the DAO library was renamed. This is nothing to do with corruption of any kind.

Comment: This worked wonderfully for when I couldn't get DAO installed due to a 32-bit Access 2003 database now upconverted to 2010 format and running in 64-bit Access.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to attempt to re-register the dao library here and doing such is a silly wild goose chase and amounts to wasting company resources. Installing Access 2003 on that computer should work just fine and installing 2003 on that computer will ALSO correctly install the DAO libraries (attempting to copy and re-register the DAO library has the potential to turn your computer into a complete mess here – don't do this and it not required).

There are either some broken references or perhaps the ADO library was placed higher up in the references as compared to the DAO library.  In fact check the references in the VBA editor. If ADO is not being used, then remove the reference.

Also if outlook is being used from this application then remove the outlook reference in this application. You REALLY need to use late binding for Outlook automation code.

I have run Access 2003 on windows 7 x64 since the win 7 beta and I had zero problems here. This is nothing to do with x64 or win7, but only that of behaviors of a typical broken reference.

Comment: There is no ADO reference in this application. Thanks for the "goose chase" comment - I am aware of that and that's how I ended up here.

Answer (score 1):

Problem ocured when x86 and x64 version of OS/Access are instaled.

1. You need to create directory (I'm sure it does not exsit and You need administrative rights to do this):
   C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DAO
2. Copy dao360.dll from C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DAO
   to the directory created in step (1)
3. Now add reference in your VBA application.

Comment: Worked form Me!!